# Does docker-compose up destroy old database?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new with docker; I have a docker-compose.yml file. My question is: if I run `docker-compose up` after modifying this file, will this remove the old postgres db?

Comment: It depends what your docker-compose file is doing. How the DB is attached to it. As container? As mounted volume? Or your container is using network to access the DB.
It depends also on your docker-compose life cycle which is defined with yaml file and all scripts around your system.

Comment: We need to see an example of your compose file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the configuration for the PostgreSQL service or one of its dependencies has changed since the last time you ran `docker-compose up`, Docker Compose will destroy and recreate the container, but the new PostgreSQL container will continue to use the same volumes as the old one.  If you're using [the official `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) (rather than an image you made yourself), all of the database's data will be stored in a Docker volume by default, and so the data will be preserved across invocations of `docker-compose up` (but *not* invocations of `docker-compose rm postgres-service` or `docker-compose down`).

Comment: If, like me, you're using external volumes, `docker-compose down` won't remove them. To do so, you must find them with `docker volume ls` and then remove them with `docker volume rm {{volume_name}}`

Comment: @jwdodder Your answer seems to imply that `docker-compose down` will NOT preserve volumes/data, but I don't think that is correct.